# Fast way to prove something that free vector space is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be any set. Then we can define the free vector space on $S$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ as the set $\mathbb{F}^S$ with componentwise addition and scalar multiplication. Is there a fast way to show that $\mathbb{F}^S$ is indeed a vector space? Verifying every single axiom is rather tedious, and their proofs are similar.

The writer believes it might be possible to prove that every statement of a certain form with symbols $+$ and $*$ from the field will imply some other statement about this vector space. For example since + is commutative in $\mathbb{F}$, and every component of a sum of vectors is a sum of elements of $\mathbb{F}$, the addition of vectors will be commutative too. So it would be nice to have an immediate way to get theorems about $\mathbb{F}^S$ from axioms that $\mathbb{F}$ satisfy, but the writer is not sure how to formalize this. Perhaps every first order formula using only $+$ and $*$ (not $\in$) in the field has an equivalent one in the vector space? This seems to work for the commutative, associative, identity and inverse formulas, but the writer doesn't see how to prove this in general if true.

Comment: I think you're right:  it's tedious but simple.

Comment: I agree. I'd note that formulating a statement about all first order formulas is going to be far less "immediate" than just checking the relevant axioms even if at the end of the day you get a machine to do that. The general idea is definitely that because things are defined componentwise, the status of your new structure as a vector space is in some sense "inherited" from the status of $\mathbb{F}$ as a vector space; there can be no violation of the axioms because it would imply a violation of the axioms in $\mathbb{F}$. But there are a whole lot of axioms. Maybe a logician can go further.

Comment: My hope might not work: integral domains have no zero divisors, but products of them do.